# Как с помощью глобального хука отменить действие мыши?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Есть мысль написать ремапер мыши. Но для этого необходимо отменять определённые действия мыши.

Есть кусок кода:

```
HHOOK myHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(myHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    myHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LowLevelMouseProc, NULL, 0); 
    if (myHook != NULL)
        printf("Hook complited;\n");
    else
        printf("Hook not complited.\n");

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(myHook);
    return 0;
}
```

Данный код работает только с ЛКМ (ЛКМ полностью перестаёт работать на всех окнах), т.е. если в условии поменять WM_LBUTTONDOWN на, например, WM_RBUTTONDOWN или WM_XBUTTONDOWN, то код перестаёт работать (и ПКМ, и боковая кнопка мыши работают как и должны работать).

Почему оно работает именно таким образом (работает с ЛКМ, но не работает с ПКМ)? И как исправить это (сделать чтобы работало с любыми кнопками мыши)?

Comment: добавьте в код строчки, которые не работают

Comment: Как раз так и этот кусок кода не работает, а если быть точнее, то функция LowLevelMouseProc. Почему он работает с ЛКМ, но не работает с ПКМ?

Comment: в том варианте который на данный момент указан в вопросе, код работает как надо?

Comment: В этом варианте да, но если в функции LowLevelMouseProc, во втором условии WM_LBUTTONDOWN поменять на WM_RBUTTONDOWN, то код перестаёт работать.

Comment: вы решили, что он не работает из-за того, что открывается контекстное меню?

Comment: В том числе. Кроме этого я пробовал и с WM_XBUTTONDOWN. На моей мыши они предназначены как "Вперёд" и "Назад". Они тоже работали.

Comment: контекстное меню открывается не при `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`, а при `WM_RBUTTONUP`. т.е. чтобы ловить попытки открыть контекст.меню проверяете `wParam` на равенство `WM_RBUTTONUP`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Теперь всё работает как надо.